# How i can to solve an Invalid operand error?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

My first goal is to make a calculator in assembly language, but I find a lot of problems that I would never have imagined before.

Before, Nasm couldn't assembly my program for an 'invalid operand' in a comparision between 2 numbers. I fix some problems.

CURRENTLY: I can to assembly and ejecute the program, but the console show a "-NaN" ask.

I hope you can to do a solution to this issue.

```
;--------------------------------------------------------------
; calculam.asm
; This program will check if a number is an INT or DOUBLE one.
; if INT it will convert to DOUBLE
; if DOUBLE it won't nothing, continue
; finally it will diplay the final DOUBLE number.
; -------------------------------------------------------------
; Assembly with GNU/Linux x80_86) & NASM compiler & GCC
; -------------------------------------------------------------
; 1) Compile:  nasm -f elf64 calculam.asm
; 2) Link: gcc -no-pie calculam.o -o calculam
; 3) Run:./calculam
; ------------------------------------------------------------

bits 64
extern printf

section .data
    a: dq 28.33
    fmt: db "Result is: %g", 10, 0

section .bss
    op1: resq 1

section .text
    global main

main:
    push rbp

.rounding:
    movsd       xmm1, qword [a]     ; load a on xmm1
    roundsd     xmm2, xmm1, 3       ; truncates xmm1 and loading to xmm2
     
        ; Extract of http://www.ray.masmcode.com/tutorial/fpuchap7.htm#ficom
        ; (i adapted to this program):

    fcom  qword[a]    ;compare ST(0) with the value of the real8_var variable
    fstsw ax          ;copy the Status Word containing the result to AX
    fwait             ;insure the previous instruction is completed
    sahf              ;transfer the condition codes to the CPU's flag register

        ;jpe error_handler ;the comparison was indeterminate
        ;                  ;this condition should be verified first
        ;                  ;then only two of the next three conditional jumps
        ;                  ;should become necessary, in whatever order is preferred,
        ;                  ;the third jump being replaced by code to handle that case
        ;ja    st0_greater ;when all flags are 0
        ;jb    st0_lower   ;only the C0 bit (CF flag) would be set if no error
        ;jz    both_equal  ;only the C3 bit (ZF flag) would be set if no error

    ja      .display
    jb      .display

    fild dword [a]  ; If both are equal xmm1=integer so we need to do it double

.display:
    fstp        qword [op1]         
    mov         rdi, fmt                
    movsd       xmm0, qword [op1]   
    mov         rax, 1                 
    call        printf            
    
    pop rbp
       
.exit:  mov rax, 0
    ret
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `cmp` is for general-purpose registers. Did you mean to use `cmpsd` or `comisd`?

Comment: Michael : 'cmpsd' don't works too. It doesn't seems something as easy :( With 'comisd' shows an 'error: mismatch in operand sizes'

Comment: `cmpsd` will give you a mask with the comparison result. If you want to update EFLAGS, use `comisd` (or `ucomisd`). Consult Intel's manual for the available instructions and how they work.

Comment: It seems it works a bit better with 'fcom' because now i can to assembly and link the program. However now i gets the answer '-Nan' (one operand its not detected by the comparision). Here's the news.

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping with your debugger?  That should provide some hints as to where the incorrect value is coming from.  (It's pretty futile to try to develop anything in assembly unless you have a debugger and know how to use it.)

Comment: All right Nate Eldrege. I've no knoledge of ddd or dbg or else. It's a bit esotheric for me still, but some day i will need "to get the bull by its horns" (an spanish topic), but by now I would like that some person could to bring me a solution, if it's possible.